# laravel not submitting simple form

Tags: php, forms, laravel, submit

I'm trying to submit a simple form but it's not redirecting or anything.

Code:

```
@foreach($admins as $admin)
    <form method="post" action="/admin/medewerkers">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="text" value="{{$admin->id}}" name="userid" hidden>
        <tr>
            <td>{{$admin->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$admin->email}}</td>
            <td><a data-target="#myModal{{$admin->id}}" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> </td>
            <td> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" name="delete" id="delete"> Delete </button></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
@endforeach
```

Simple backend

```
public function update(Request $request)
{ 
  if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    echo 'delete';
  }
}
```

What am i doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Your markup is invalid. You can't have a `form` tag wrapping one `tr` only.

Comment: Ah i see, what would be a good solution to fix this? i can't put it outside of the foreach since i need a seperate form for each delete button

Comment: @cmac But i don't think the controller is the problem since it's not even submitting

Comment: Put submit button outside tr and see if works

Comment: Is it doing anything? What happens when you click submit button?

Comment: Did not happen anything if i click the submit, @B. Desai solution worked tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use form containing `<tr> only`
try this:

```
@foreach($admins as $admin)


        <tr>
            <td>{{$admin->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$admin->email}}</td>
            <td><a data-target="#myModal{{$admin->id}}" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> </td>
            <td> <form method="post" action="/admin/medewerkers"> 
                 {{csrf_field()}}
                <input type="text" value="{{$admin->id}}" name="userid" hidden> 
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" name="delete" id="delete"> Delete </button> </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Yass! this works thank you! will accept answer soon as i can.